# Compiler Error for method

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I'm having trouble with a little program I'm making. Basically I have 6 Classes. 1 main class, 4 sub classes that "extend" the main class and another class to run the program. The class to run the program is laid out this so far:

```
public class ClassToRunProgram {

public void main(String[] args){

Class1 a = new Class1(0, "class1"); //I've created 1 main class (Class5) that 
Class2 b = new Class2(1, "class2"); //these 4 classes extend.
Class3 c = new Class3(2, "class3");
Class4 d = new Class4(3, "class4");

int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() *3);

Class5[] arrayForClasses = new Class5[]{a, b, c, d}; //since they're extending this
                                                    //class I want to make them into
                                                   //a single Array?


    String numberQuestion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
"What question do you want to ask? \n 
Enter a number: \n 
1. First Question? \n 
2. Second Question? \n 
3. Third Question?");

int question = Integer.parseInt(numberQuestion); //not sure if this part is 
                                                //actually relevant at all??
                                               //Think it might be since I want to
                                              //use integers in my if statement below


if(question == 1){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Blah blah"+arrayForClasses.getReturnValue()+" blah");
}
```

The .getReturnValue() method is within all of the classes (1-5). I'm not sure if this is actually what I have to do. But the problem I'm having is that when I compile it (even though it's not finished) it throws up a "CANNOT FIND SYMBOL" error with the message "symbol: method .getReturnValue() location: variable arrayForClasses type Class5[]". I'm just wondering where am I going wrong with this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `arrayForClasses` is an array; it doesn't have a method called `getReturnValue()`.

Comment: The arrayForClasses is an Class5[], that is an array - and arrays don't have the getReturnValue() method. You really don't need 5 classes, you need 1 class "Question" and you should make 4 (or other amount) of instances of that class - one for each question.

Comment: Call the method `getReturnValue()` using array indexes like this `arrayForClasses[0].getReturnValue()`.

Comment: The multiline string won't compile either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arrayForClasses` is an array, and you can't ever add methods to arrays, only to the objects *inside* the arrays. You need to call the method on the objects in the array, not the array itself. So something like

```
arrayForClasses[0].getReturnValue()
```

Now, I say "something like" because I'm having a hard time following what you're trying to do, and I'm a little concerned about this idea of putting the "getReturnValue()" method into many different classes without a specific reason to do so.

Comment: I put the "getReturnValue()" method into all the classes because I was worried that it wouldn't call it. I just took them out and left it in the main class and changed it to the "arrayForClasses[0]" as you showed me above and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`arrayForClasses` is an array; it is not one of the classes it contains objects of, so it does not have a `getReturnValue()` method

You need to access an element of the array (that *is* an object of `Class5` or one of its subclasses), and call `getReturnValue()` on that:

```
arrayForClasses[0].getReturnValue()
```

The index can go from 0 to 3 (total 4 elements) an you can use either one.  You can even access all of them in a loop:

```
for (Class5 elem : arrayForClasses) { // cycles through each element in order
  elem.getReturnValue();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That really helped with another problem that just cropped up too!